# How do you use proxy with the whois command?

Tags: proxy, whois

I tried exporting into http_proxy and https_proxy but that didn't seem to work.

I am guessing that there is another way to use a proxy when querying whois information from the command line?

Answer (score 5):

The whois command talks in a specific protocol and port, namely `whois      43/tcp` ; so obviously trying to use an HTTP(S) (HTTP port 80/tcp and HTTPS 443/tcp by default).

So HTTP proxies-aware won't work, as those protocols are not involved with the inner workings of the whois protocol.

If you need to setup an external proxy, you would need a socks aware proxy, as this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718836/how-can-i-implement-a-simple-whois-proxy-in-perl

For a Whois proxy in python, see [uwhoisd](https://github.com/kgaughan/uwhoisd) and for further clarifications on how to use it: [python: how to perform whois with uwhoisd proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922964/python-how-to-perform-whois-with-uwhoisd-proxy)

see also [About the WHOIS Protocol](https://gkbrk.com/2016/08/about-the-whois-protocol/)

> The WHOIS protocol is a simple, plaintext-based protocol that listens
> on TCP port 43. There is an RFC that defines the protocol, [RFC 3912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912).

Comment: This link explains how to do this in perl, how do you do this in python?

Comment: @HashWizard added to the answer.

Comment: My main objective is to get past the limitations of the query server, say to query 10 times instead of 5 times (which is the limit) by using public proxies.  Would the solution that you provided allow me to do that ? Thanks for taking the time to address my problem

Comment: Because from the looks of it, the solution doesn't seem to be accepting different proxies (proxies provided by me) , the solution seems to be a 'proxy' /intermediary' for solving domain extension ambiguities (for example getting the correcting results if I whois something.com and something.org)

Answer (score 2):

[WHOIS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912) is a TCP/IP protocol, HTTP doesn't play a part in the query and so an HTTP proxy won't work.

If your proxy server also presents a SOCKS interface, you could attempt to use [tsocks or proxychains-ng as described here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Proxy_settings#Using_a_SOCKS_proxy) to perform the query.

Answer (score 2):

for me this worked:

```
ncat --listen --exec '/usr/bin/ncat --proxy <proxy_ip>:<proxy_port> whois.ripe.net 43' 8043 &
```

the query:

```
whois --host localhost --port 8043 <ip_that_i_want_to_whois>
```

Comment: this is a socks5 proxy that you used with ncat?

Comment: no, this is a http proxy i guess for socks5 u need to add `--proxy-type socks5` the default is http according to `man ncat`

Comment: thanks Booker B
worked for me, but unfortunately I couldn't find a workaround to close the ncat connection when the data is received via the proxy-ied connection

Comment: ctrl+c should work

Comment: yes, sure, but I wanted to have a non-interactive script, thus sending additional signals is not desired. Nevertheless, thank you for your example.

Comment: you could add `-i 1` for a 1 second idle time. This should close the proxy connection after 1sec. (add it to the second ncat which initiates the proxy connection)

lower values are also possible like `--idle-timeout 200ms`

Answer (score 0):

if you allow port 43 to egress your http proxies then you can use a shell script to do the deed via an explicit `CONNECT` request

passing `$1` as the `whois` host eg `whois.nic.iana`, , `$2` as the query and `$3` as the proxy host

```
#!/bin/sh
(
sleep 1
echo "CONNECT $1:43 HTTP/1.1"
echo ""

sleep 2
echo "$2"
echo ""
sleep 4

) | telnet $3 8080
```